# How to find shapes with >180º angles and concave inward white ovals

Tags: python, opencv

I want to find shapes with concave circles "carved in" into the shape itself.
Hard to explain with words. Here's some example images:

| Shape | Shape with my markers |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

On the left, you can see the example shape that opencv finds using `findContours` function.
On the right, I marked in red some of the pointy/sharp edges (high angles) and I marked most oval "carved in" shapes.

I pay special attention to the oval carved in shape because that one is very distinctive from the noise that is also captured as shapes, from the original image.

So the problem boils down to:
Given the opencv shapes finding the shapes which:

1. Have concave shapes cut in in background color, at the margins
2. Have angles of >180º between some (min one quarter) of such shapes inwards.

Unfortunately, the original images may not be shown due to NDA. I did get permission to show you those and guarantee you that fulfilling those two conditions, I can find what we want.

Here's the code I use to get the contours

```
    img = np.asarray(image)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # setting threshold of gray image
    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        # etc...
```

Here's the functions I thought would help me but ended up not helping me finding the angles and the concave shapes:

1. `cv2.approxPolyDP` <- Gives me an approximate poly but I don't know how to compare it to find the concave shapes.
2. `cv2.boundingRect` <- Helps me finding the coordinates where the pointing elements may be by overlaping coordinates but I don't know how to calculate the difference between a sharp angle and a smooth circle with numpy. However, I would still be missing many elements.

Comment: have a look at opencv's convexityDefect function. If it's possible to find the the outer oval pointer of your contour with this, the rest might be simple.

Comment: Consider finding the edges, low pass filter them, and identify areas that stay pointy

Comment: @Micka Oh! https://theailearner.com/2020/11/09/convexity-defects-opencv/. Nice. That puts me some steps closer... Then I will need to figure out how to detect the relative position of the dots. Whether inside or outside. Also how to detect the angle at the edges. It is a good place to start, though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I'm still too new for the opencv library. I don't know what opencv has to provide that. I'll see if I can find some guide or teaching source that explains how to do the "pointy" identification

Comment: @Micka https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668824/551625 Do you think that is what I need? I'm still thinking about how can I fit an ellipse for calculation purposes (in that answer, the ellipses are already there in the image), when I only have half of it. I'm researching that